# How to programatically check if a imageview has any background drawable attached to it

Tags: android, android-imageview

**What i have::** *I have a imageview below for which i have attached a background drawable*

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/myId"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/plus" />
```

**What I am trying to find::** *How can i check programmatically, if that imageview object has background drawable attached to it*

Comment: Why the downvote ? ... i have searched Stack-overflow, there is not question regarding this ?

Comment: I think `ImageView.getBackground()` will return `null` if there is no background drawable, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the `getBackground()` method is what you want. You got down voted because this is a trivial issue.

```
ImageView yourImageView = findViewById(R.id.myId);
Drawable background = yourImageView.getBackground();
if(background != null)
    System.out.println("View has background!");
else
    System.out.println("View has no background!");
```

Comment: Did anybody try this? At least for me it does not work with a simple ImageView that has no background whatsoever. It instead returns a StateListDrawable with the same size as the view, but simply "nothing drawn" in it. (Tested with Samsung Galaxy S4, target SDK Version 21)

Answer (score 0):

```
ImageView myimage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.img_call_icon);
myimage.setTag(R.drawable.myicon);
myimage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.myicon);
myimage.
        Object tag = myimage.getTag();
        int id = tag == null ? -1 : (int) tag;
        switch (id) {
        case R.drawable.icon:
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "skype", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;

        case R.drawable.myicon:
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "call", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        }
```